# Is there a 'simple' function that flips the order of positive numbers without making them negative?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions, real-numbers, monotone-functions

If I want to flip the order of some numbers, I can just multiply them with -1. But is there a *not too complicated* way to do it such that the numbers remain positive?

Here's my attempt to word the question a bit more formally if you prefer that:

Is there a simple* function that maps from $\mathbb{R} \to S$ where $S \subseteq \mathbb{R} \ $ s.t.:
$$ \ \forall x \colon \forall y \colon (x \in \mathbb{R}) \wedge (y \in \mathbb{R}) \wedge (x < y)  \rightarrow (f(x) > f(y)) \wedge (f(x) > 0) \wedge (f(y) > 0)$$

Its fine even its from $\mathbb{N} \to S$ or something.

*I know this is vague, but I just mean like obviously I know there is *some* function but I want one I can use.

Thank you!

Comment: If the max number is $~M,~$ then $~f(x) = M+1 - x~$ works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ given by $f(x)=e^{-x}.$

This is a positive strictly decreasing function.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @IbrahimHasaan no prob!

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = 1/x \text{ if } x\gt0$,

otherwise $f(x)=x$.

Comment: For your function, $-2<-1$ yet $f(-2)$ is not greater than $f(-1).$ Perhaps you meant otherwise $f(x)=-x.$

Comment: Just noticed another small problem: OP wants $f(x)>0$ for all reals, yet you have $f(0)=0.$

Comment: Oh, such a simple one! How did I not think of this? Thank you!

Comment: @IbrahimHasaan - Yeah, this is the one to go with if you only really care about positive numbers. But the $e^{-x}$ is better overall - you picked the right one to checkmark.